# How do I omit border from footer of SSRS report?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a ssrs report with two columns. I need to put a border around the report but I dont want it around the footer. How do I omit the border from the footer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you put a Border on the Report which includes the Header and Footer.

[image]

Instead of putting the border on the whole reprot, you can put a border on the body.

[image]

Or the table.

[image]